# Removing library files from aar crashes app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

In build.gradle file for kotlin project I am using below packaging option,

```
android.packagingOptions.jniLibs.excludes("**/*.so")
```

Which is removing .so files from aar files generated. This is what I want but apk is crashing due to not able to find .so.

Is there a way I can generate aar files without .so but apk can still find .so.
It is also present at below location.

\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj

Comment: aar files are designed to contain the necessary native .so libraries. Why do you want to change it?